# Byte overflow evaluate to zero instead of exception?

Tags: c#, .net

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  int n;
  byte b;
  n = 256;
  b = (byte) n;
  Console.WriteLine(b); //0
}
```

C# byte range is 0 to 255 and hence I try to cast an int of 256 to byte and see what will happen.

Surprisingly it returns 0 instead of 255 or better yet give me an overflow exception?

**UPDATES:**
I'm trying it on macos which is Mono, if it matters and .NET Framework 4.7

Comment: 256 in binary is 1 0000 0000 and a byte just contains 8 bits, so when you cast 256 to byte, the left-hand side 1 will be ignored

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/checked-compiler-option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the expected behaviour. If you think about it, 256 is one "1" followed by 8 zeroes in binary. When you take away everything except the least significant 8 bits, you get 8 zeroes, which is the value 0.

From the C# language specification §6.2.1:

> For a conversion from an integral type to another integral type, the
>   processing depends on the overflow checking context (§7.6.12) in which
>   the conversion takes place:
>
> - In a `checked` context, the conversion succeeds if the value of the source operand is within the range of the destination type, but throws
>     a `System.OverflowException` if the value of the source operand is
>     outside the range of the destination type.
> - In an `unchecked` context, the conversion always succeeds, and proceeds as follows.
>
>   - If the source type is larger than the destination type, then the source value is truncated by discarding its “extra” most significant
>       bits. The result is then treated as a value of the destination type.

If you want an exception, you can used `checked`:

```
b = checked((byte) n);
```

Comment: Great! But is that also means that in order to have a absolute predictable outcome when dealing with numbers, it's recommended to have `checked` on every arithmetic operations? Or type casting?

Comment: If you always want exception when overflow occurs, then you should put `checked` whenever there is possibility of overflow. But sometimes "wrapping around" might be preferred though. @Isaac

Comment: Out of curiosity, since this involves in another additional checking, will it affect the performance in anyway? Or its neglectable?

Comment: @Isaac It does add an additional check, but really, you should only deal with performance problems when you actually have them, and that you are sure that it's caused by `checked` statements, not some other code, which is unlikely.

Comment: If you want it to always throw an exception, you can add the `-checked` compiler option, in .csproj file it would be `<CheckForOverflowUnderflow>true</CheckForOverflowUnderflow>`

Answer (score 2):

I would like to complement the previous answer.

Take a look at this:

255 -> 11111111 +

001 -> 00000001

256 -> **1**00000000

As you can see. We have 256 in binary format, but as your number is eight bits, **1** can't be stored. This leave the number 00000000 which is zero.

This is more theory than C# specific question. But i think this is important to understand.